# Over what time period is 'Today' measured for the Game Center leaderboard?

Tags: game-center, leaderboard

Does anyone know over what time period the Game Center leaderboards measure 'Today'?  In other words, if I play a game and get a high score for 'Today', at what time does that score no longer appear in the 'Today' category?

Answer (score 0):

12:00 AM PTZ <== that's where apple is

Answer (score 0):

"Today" in Apple's Game Center really means the most relevant score in the past 24 hours (even though this can easily span more than one actual day).

Here's a reference to the time scope documentation for GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday:

> Each player is restricted to scores recorded in the past 24 hours.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday